# Logging in django is not outputting anything

Tags: python, django

I was having issues with print statements and Django and I saw on here that its better to do logging. I am not sure what I am doing wrong though. It logs sometimes to console and other times it doesn't for the same page and I cant get it to log anything in my post method.

I have tried doing the `logger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")`  above all the class views, ive tried adding that line to each individual method and ive tried only having it in 1 at a time. Any thoughts?

**Settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for caspers_trading_tools project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-d^@mw27((%t$wzj+3eykdmfmweufzep44sgkhib)^n1thdh!y6'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'landing_page',
    'trading_log',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'caspers_trading_tools.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / "templates", 
            BASE_DIR / "templates" / "includes"
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'caspers_trading_tools.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [ 
    BASE_DIR / "static"
]

 
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'mylogger': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

**Views.py**

```
class CreateOrderView(View):
    def get(self, request,):
        logger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")
        logger.info("TEST")
        # this should be removed once user_ids are implemented through login system and session creation
        request.session["user_id"] = 1
        # should be set to session.get("user_id") probably in the future
        user_id = request.session.get("user_id")
        trade_form = CreateTradeForm()
        order_form = CreateOrderForm()

        context = {}
        context["user_id"] = user_id
        context["order_form"] = order_form
        context["trade_form"] = trade_form
        return render(request, "trading_log/add-order.html", context)

    def post(self, request):
        trade_form = CreateTradeView(request.POST)
        order_form = CreateOrderForm(request.POST)
        trade = trade_form.save(commit=False)
        order = order_form.save(commit=False)

        logger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")
        logger.info("TEST")
        # logger.info("TRADE", trade)
        # logger.info("ORDER", order)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("add-order-page"))
```

If you need any other files please let me know. I dont think ive done anything anywhere to make logging work.

[image: Post getting hit but no logging appearing]

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using the [`RequireDebugTrue`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue) filter, which means that you will only get logs printed if `DEBUG` is set to `True` in your settings file (which you do not show in your post).

Additionally, you do not need to set the `logger` variable in every single method. It's ok to declare it once per module globally.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. I do have debug = True in my settings file. I still cant get this to work. Have been messing with it all day. Really lost on what to do now. Added full settings file to my post. When I refresh the page it doesnt do a new request in the console most. Could that be an issue in some way? As I said it shows up in get() sometimes but never in post().

Comment: I'm, guessing that by "console" you mean the browser's, which would indeed indicate that the request is not being made, which would of course explain the lack of logs as your code is not being executed. Try disabling caching for all requests in your browser's dev tools or even using CURL for testing purposes.